# Evaluation of the partial derivative of an indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, indefinite-integrals

I want to evaluate the partial derivative of the integral stated below, with respect to $x$ and  $\dot x$, respectively.

The integral is $I=\dot x \int \frac {1}{\dot {x}^2} f (x,\dot x) d\dot x$

I know about Leibnitz Rule but it is applicable only for definite integrals. Should I just interchange the differentiation and integration signs and carry out the necessary calculations?

Comment: Do $x=x(t)$ and $\dot{x}=\dot{x}(t)$?

Comment: @NgChungTak Not mentioned in the question. But I think that that is what it is.

Comment: Define $f (x,\dot x)$ No definition no go!

Comment: @926reals As mentioned in the question, it is a constant of motion and a function of $x $ and $\dot x $.

Comment: So $f (x,\dot x)$ is a constant of motion. Interesting,